# Can I power a 9g servo from an arduino nano with USB power only?

Tags: power, usb, arduino-nano, servo

I want to run a 9g servo off of the pins from an arduino nano board, using only the 5v USB connection.

The servo specifically is a SG90, which I have measured a stall current of ~250mA - I don't intend to stall it, just have it run with almost no load

I am not sure which pins to power it off of from the arduino itself - do I use the VCC or the +5v? does it matter which ground I use? should I use a breadboard to help me place any other components that may be needed, i.e. a capacitor or something? does the arduino nano negotiate to get more than the default of 100mA from a USB power connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The max current of the Arduino-Nano 5V Pin is 200mA. So if you draw more than that it might damage your Arduino.</strike>

Here is an interesting summary regarding the Maximum Ratings of the Arduino Nano: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/how-much-current-can-i-draw-from-the-arduinos-pins

> The 5V pin of the arduino is not connected through the
>   microcontroller. As such, it can source significantly more power. When
>   you are powering your arduino from USB, the USB interface limits your
>   total power consumption to 500 mA.

So yes, it actually seems you can draw 250mA out of the 5V PIN.

> do I use the VCC or the +5v?

You use +5V, because VCC is for powering your Arduino with an external Power Source. It allows you to use up to 7-12V (recommended), or up to 6-20V (limits).

> does it matter which ground I use?

Doesn't matter

> should I use a breadboard to help me place any other components that may be needed, i.e. a capacitor or something?

A breadboard makes it easier for you, to test your circuit. But you can do it without if you like. Then you possibly have to solder some connections

See also the [offical Arduino Page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardNano) for the Nano.

Comment: Thanks - might I ask a few more details - does the arduino negotiate for more than 100mA with the computer when connected to one, and also what would happen if more than 200mA are drawn - would it just lower the voltage and become temporarily unstable, or would something overheat? (does it even go through anything, or is it directly connected to the USB port?) - the breadboard was for if any extra components would be helpful, i.e. a capacitor or diode or something to keep the signal "clean" for the arduino

Comment: Isn't the 200mA limit only for when the board is power via VIN and not USB?

Comment: @Gerben Thank you. I researched it and you're right. Actually the USB-current-limit is much higher then 200mA. I have updated my answer. Source http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/how-much-current-can-i-draw-from-the-arduinos-pins